# SQL Server 2008 R2 not using allocated Memory

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008, vmware

I have a sql instance that is running through a VM. The VM has 32gb of memory allocated to it, and I have setup to use 28gb. However, looking at the memory usage, I only see SQL using about a 1gb. It also shows that all but 1gb is free however the processes in use do not add up to 31gb. Not even close, I see maybe 3gb total.

### I have attached some TSQL results for memory usage.

```
Memory usage details for SQL Server instance- X64) - Enterprise Edition (64-bit))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Memory visible to the Operating System

Physical Memory_MB                      Physical Memory_GB                      Virtual Memory GB
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
32768                                   32                                      8192


-------------------------------
Buffer Pool Usage at the Moment

BPool_Committed_MB                      BPool_Commit_Tgt_MB                     BPool_Visible_MB
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
28672.000000                            28672.000000                            28672.000000


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Memory used by SQL Server Buffer Pool as reported by Perfmon counters

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
29360128             28672.000000                            28.000000000


-------------------------------------------------------------
Memory needed as per current Workload for SQL Server instance

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
29360128             28672.000000                            28.000000000


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total amount of dynamic memory the server is using for maintaining connections

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
5288                 5.164062                                0.005043029


------------------------------------------------------------
Total amount of dynamic memory the server is using for locks

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
31248                30.515625                               0.029800415


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total amount of dynamic memory the server is using for the dynamic SQL cache

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
40752                39.796875                               0.038864135


-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total amount of dynamic memory the server is using for query optimization

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
2528                 2.468750                                0.002410888


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total amount of dynamic memory used for hash, sort and create index operations.

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
0                    0.000000                                0.000000000


------------------------------------------
Total Amount of memory consumed by cursors

Mem_KB               Mem_MB                                  Mem_GB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1832                 1.789062                                0.001747131


-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of pages in the buffer pool (includes database, free, and stolen).

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
3670016              29360128.000000                         28672.000000000


---------------------------------------
Number of Data pages in the buffer pool

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1429714              11437712.000000                         11169.640625000


---------------------------------------
Number of Free pages in the buffer pool

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1887521              15100168.000000                         14746.257812500


-------------------------------------------
Number of Reserved pages in the buffer pool

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
0                    0.000000                                0.000000000


-----------------------------------------
Number of Stolen pages in the buffer pool

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
352781               2822248.000000                          2756.101562500


---------------------------------------------
Number of Plan Cache pages in the buffer pool

8KB_Pages            Pages_in_KB                             Pages_in_MB
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
357949               2863592.000000                          2796.476562500


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page Life Expectancy - Number of seconds a page will stay in the buffer pool without references

Page Life in seconds PLE Status
-------------------- ------------------
81046                PLE is Healthy


--------------------------------------------------------------
Number of requests per second that had to wait for a free page

Free list stalls/sec
--------------------
77


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of pages flushed to disk/sec by a checkpoint or other operation that require all dirty pages to be flushed

Checkpoint pages/sec
--------------------
786108


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of buffers written per second by the buffer manager"s lazy writer

Lazy writes/sec
--------------------
5157


--------------------------------------------------------------
Total number of processes waiting for a workspace memory grant

Memory Grants Pending
---------------------
0


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total number of processes that have successfully acquired a workspace memory grant

Memory Grants Outstanding
-------------------------
0
```

Per Shanky's Request.

```
physical_memory_in_use_kb = 30784516
large_page_allocations_kb = 196608  
locked_page_allocations_kb = 30285504
total_virtual_address_space_kb = 8589934464
virtual_address_space_reserved_kb = 34544372    
virtual_address_space_committed_kb = 31110044
virtual_address_space_available_kb = 8555390092
page_fault_count = 1706349
memory_utilization_percentage = 100
available_commit_limit_kb = 34625996
process_physical_memory_low = 0
process_virtual_memory_low = 0
```

So based on this, it looks like everything look great. But that doesn't explain why the server begins to slow down over time like the memory is being stolen for other VM's. This question may have turned into something completely different after seeing these results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much memory is allocated to SQL Server Via max server memory. The information you posted did not included that.

Can you also add output of below query in question please format the question so that output is clear and visible

```
select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

You should NEVER look at task manager for SQL Server memory consumption. Its a windows tool and only gives information about [Working Set memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/05/18/sql-and-the-working-set.aspx) NOT the total memory consumed by SQL Server. If SQL server service account is running under Local system or the service account has Locked pages in memory privilege(LPIM) task manager would not show memory allocated by AWE API(or the locked memory) .

The working set memory shown by task manager can be paged by OS but memory allocated by AWE API(when SQL Server service account has LPIM) cannot be paged out that is why it is called `locked`. In your case I guess SQL Server service account has LPIM so task manager is not showing memory allocated by AWE API just the working set

In output on query if you see some value for locked_page_allocations_kb then SQL account has LPIM.

**Edit:**

From query result

```
locked_page_allocations_kb = 30285504~ 28 G
```

This is one part of total memory utilized by SQL Server (the memory which is locked) this would not be shown under Task manager. Task manager would not show this because it is NON PAGEABLE memory and task manager only reports working set which is pageable.

Now you asked about why SQL Server memory consumption rose when you ran big query this is because buffer pool started fetching new pages which caused memory consumption to grow hence utilization increased

Comment: Added what you asked for in the main question. I think this has turned into a whole different question after seeing the results of that query. On a side note is this why on my personal computer when I run a large query i can see my memory usage increase, since i am using a different account to run the service?